# how to use filter effect on checkbox in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to use `filter-effect` whenever user click on `checkbox`?

As per below image, there is filter page. what i am trying to do is whenever user will click on checkbox the value should be return as output as per below `filtering api data`, But i am getting a `null` value instead.

image:

[image]

end-point url : http://localhost:8000/api/filter/ 

filter category api-data:

```
{
 "product_categoryData": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "category_title": "category01"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "category_title": "category02"
        },
    ],

 "filter_colorData": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "color_title": "black",
            "color_hex_code": "#000000"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "color_title": "red",
            "color_hex_code": "#43243dsf"
        },

    ],

  //(so on...)
}
```

After filtering product filter api-data,
end point-url: http://localhost:8000/api/p_list?product_category=1&min_price=&max_price=&color=&size=

```
[
    {
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/p/product01",
        "id": 1,
        "title": "product01",
        "slug": "product01",
        "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/product2_EMWEgQI.png",
        "price": 5,
        "status": true,
        "created_on": "2020-04-19T18:44:03Z"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/p/product07",
        "id": 8,
        "title": "product07",
        "slug": "product07",
        "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/product4_CKX7xsA.png",
        "price": 8,
        "status": true,
        "created_on": "2020-04-19T18:44:03Z"
    }
]
```

./src/Filter.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.state = {
      response: "",
      filter_response: "",

      category_value : "",
      min_price: "",
      max_price: "",
      color_value: "",
      size_value: "",
    };

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  filterClick = (value) => {
    this.setState({category_value: value, min_price: value, max_price: value, color_value: value,
      size_value: value}, this.fetchFilterEffectData);
  };



  fetchData = async () => {

    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:8000/api/filter/`
      );

      const JsonResponse = await response.json();
      this.setState({ response: JsonResponse });
    } 
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };



  fetchFilterEffectData = async () => {

    try {
      const filter_response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:8000/api/p_list?product_category=${this.state.category_value}&min_price=${this.state.min_price}&max_price=${this.state.max_price}&color=${this.state.color_value}&size=${this.state.size_value}`
      );

      const JsonFilterResponse = await filter_response.json();
      this.setState({ filter_response: JsonFilterResponse });
    } 
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };



  render() {
    const { response } = this.state;

    if (!response) {
      return "Loading...";
    }

    return (
      <div>
                //Before Effect 
                     <div class="select_option_list">Category <i class="right fas fa-caret-down"></i> </div>
                          <div class="select_option_dropdown">
                           {response.product_categoryData.map((response) =>(

                              <div class="form-check form-check-outline">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"/>
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1"><a href="#" onClick={() => this.filterClick(response.id)}>{response.category_title}</a></label>

                              </div>

                              ))}
                          </div>
                      </div>

       //After Effect 

         {filter_response.map((response) =>(

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="blog-entry animate d-md-flex">

                    <img src={response.image} className="App-logo"/>

                    <div class="text text-2 pl-md-4">

                      <h3 class="mb-2">{response.title}</h3>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))}



      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You are filtering all the attributes with the same value in filterClick?

Comment: yes. i already doubled checked everything but it's seems like everything is okay. But i do not know why i am getting a `null` value instead. @MD.TabishMahfuz